# Must an artinian R-module have a simple R-submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an artinian $R$-module, then by the definition; for every descending chain of $R$-submodules $M_i, \: (i = 0,1,2,...)$ of $M$, the chain must become stationary for some $i=k$. Now I assume that there does not exists an $R$-submodule which is simple. If we consider a chain of descending $R$-submodules which becomes stationary for $i=k$, implying that $M_k$ does not have any proper $R$-submodules, but since I assumed that no simple $R$-submodules existed, the chain cannot become stationary unless $M_k = (0)$, in which case $M_{k-1}$ is simple. Is this argument correct? And if not, in which case does an artinian $R$-module have a simple $R$-submodule?

Sorry if this is very elementary, I just started to wonder while working through some problems.

Comment: This statement is true, and your argument is almost correct: however there is no reason to conclude that $M_k$ has no proper submodules.

Comment: @Crostul If instead I conclude that $M_k$ does not have any submodules apart from itself and $(0)$, would that be correct? It seems to me that if that's not the case, the chain does not become stationary at $i=k$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

perhaps the *reductio* argument is what introduces the complexity? we may argue slightly more directly:

let $M_0 \ne 0$ be a module. for any $n \ge 0$ if $M_n$ is not simple, then it has a proper submodule $M_{n+1}$ - here *proper* includes *non-trivial*.

the chain $M_0 \supset \dots$ has a terminal element $M_n \ne 0$ for some $n \ge 0$. by construction, $M_n$ has no proper submodules and is therefore simple.

Comment: Right, this is more straight forward. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Note that if $M$ is Artinian every collection of submodules of $M$ admits a minimal element. Consider the collection of nonzero submodules of $M$; and take a minimal element $N$ of this collection. This is a simple submodule of $M$.

Comment: Thank you, that was clean and simple (no pun intended) argument.